# in frontend logon, ajax stays logged in but axios does not after page refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, axios

i'm trying to understand the difference between ajax and axios. i'm experimenting with two request methods for user login in react development using ajax and axios -- with all else being equal. when reloading the page after successful login using ajax, the user remains logged on, but when using axios, the user is no longer logged in after page refresh. is this difference expected?

**loginPageAjax.js**

```
componentDidMount() {
  $.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/retrieveUser',
    success: (res) => {
    if (res.id) this.loginCheck(res);
    }
  });
}
```

**loginPageAxios.js**

```
componentDidMount() {
  axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/retrieveUser'
  })
  .then(res => {
    if (res.id) this.loginCheck(res);
  })
}
```

Comment: To understand this, I would look at the request in the dev console, and in particular at the headers in the request. I guess ajax includes some authentication headers and cookies by default whereas axios does not? This seems to confirm the former: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/mozAnon.

Comment: thank you christian. the issue seems to be related to the data structure. what worked for me were two updates in the axios version: from res.id to res.data.id and from res to res.data